# Google Page Speed Extension score

Tags: google-chrome, pagespeed

I am using Google Page Speed Extension in my browser to test my local setup. However, the extension does not show me a score. The online Page Speed shows a score. Any pointers as to if and where can this score be found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the place to enable the setting to display the score. Go to Settings -> Extensions -> Page Speed Score -> Options and click on "Show PageSpeed score in the overview summary."

By default this setting is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Browser extensions where always behind on updates, therefore it is better to use the Web version of PageSpeed Insights (which is more up-to-date).

Comment: However as far as I have checked, web version of PageSpeed does not allows you to check local development environments which are not open to public internet. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is working as intended. Page Speed can't fully analyze local files. Many of the Page Speed rules rely on checking request/response HTTP headers, which don't exist when loading file:// URLs.

Comment: Yes, exactly so then how do I get a score for local development environments? And that was my initial question as well.

Comment: I do not think the page can be properly evaluated when it is not online. This is probably why there is no score. You could try running an HTTP server on your machine, and pointing Page Speed at a localhost URL.